# When rendered, the results go haywire

Tags: rendering

It looks nice in the viewport, but when I render it, various parts of the image become absurd. Why does this happen?please help me.
[image: in Viewport]
[image: in Render]

Comment: look into the modifiers visibility options

Comment: All modifiers are already applied, but does it matter to the render results?

Comment: yes if you disable their visibility for render, but maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: uploading the blend file is the fastest way to solve most issues

Comment: k,Here's the file.https://github.com/muroyamei/somefiles/raw/main/20220321-2.blend

Comment: As Crantisz says, you have hidden some objects for preview but not for render, look into the BackUps collection, or press Alt H

Comment: fuck me, I had missed it.

Comment: sorry guys. I was an idiot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure that you have some hidden objects that's not hidden in the render, like this rim light:

[image]

I don't see this on screenshot, maybe this object is in the hidden part of Outliner

Comment: thank you very much !